# Как получить список и направление связей между объектами в Visio?

Tags: python, python-3.x, vba, visio

У меня есть большая схема в `Visio`, с большим количеством связей между объектами.

Я бы хотел узнать, какие есть связи у данного объекта(откуда связь идет, куда связи идет, как эта связь подписана).

Способ достижения цели не важен, единственное он должен быть не ручным.

Пробовал делать через `Visio`, жмякая на объект и просматривая инфу по нему, но там не нашел.

Еще через `python 3.x`, но там очень слабая [библиотека](https://pypi.org/project/vsdx/), которая не предоставляет такую информацию

Answer (score 0):

В русскоязычном форуме Visio была ветка про это
[Справка по соединениям в Visio](https://visio.getbb.ru/viewtopic.php?f=39&t=1142)

(Справка по соединениям фигур(шейпов) для новичков осваивающих VBA в MS Visio)

Comment: Ваш ответ можно улучшить с помощью дополнительной информации. Пожалуйста, нажмите [edit] для добавления подробностей, например, цитат или документации, чтобы другие могли подтвердить правильность вашего ответа. Вы можете найти дополнительную информацию о том, как писать хорошие ответы [в Справке](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: [Ссылки на внешние ресурсы — это прекрасно, но оставьте вместе со ссылкой описание, чтобы другие пользователи имели представление о её содержимом. Всегда цитируйте самую необходимую информацию, которую вы взяли из указанного источника, на случай если он недоступен или навсегда закрыт.](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer)